# Run access query without duplicates

Tags: ms-access

I have a database with parent table (A) and child table (B). It's a one-to-many relationship from A to B.

How can I run a query that counts the amount of entries in table A that have data greater than -9 (for a single variable) in table B? When I run the query, it's pulling all people from A that have data in table B but is creating duplicates lines for the multiple entries in table B (understandably so). How can I just *count* the amount of unique entries?

Answer (score 1):

A subquery can get you what you need:

```
select count(a.foo)
from (
         select distinct a.foo 
         from tbl_A inner join tbl_B on a.foo = b.bar
     ) as a
```

Comment: Any way to do this without writing SQL within Access?

Comment: @ChrisRay Either you write this in an query, or you write the query inside a VBA module... so... what do you prefer?

Comment: I prefer the click-and-go from design view, haha but I guess that's not possible by the sound of it

Comment: @ChrisRay At some point, you have to get your hands dirty... the sooner the better. Learn how to write SQL queries, and your life will go easier sooner

Comment: Luckily, I'm in a class that teaches SQL! I worry about everyone else, though. My super would like our team to be able to run their own queries instead of relying on me, but no one is SQL proficient.

Comment: @ChrisRay Access is a good tool for learning purposes, but it lacks some useful tools present in other RDBMSs (for example, MySQL supports `count(distinct foo)` which would be a one-step way to solve your issue without subqueries. If you're stuck (for the time being) with Access, I can only advise you (and your team) to learn everything you can, including how to write good queries using the SQL view. Once you've aquired those skills, you'll be able to "jump" to other, more robust database systems

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select distinct tblA.fldA, count(tblA.fldA) 
From tblA Inner Join tblB
ON tblA.fldAID = tblB.fldAID
```